# Another Basic VBO Setup

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, vbo, glew

I'm attempting to render a cube using a VBO with GLUT and Glew. I've checked my strides, I'm swapping my buffers, I initialize the VBO after GLUT is initialized, I'm (as far as I can tell) using the correct data types. My code loosely follows [this tutorial](http://sdickinson.com/wordpress/?p=122).

The relevant section of my code:

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "include.h"
#include "terrain.h"
#include <math.h>

#define NULL 0

float angle = 0.0f;
float lx = 0.0f, lz = -1.0f;
float x = 0.0f, z = 5.0f;


GLuint vboID;
GLuint indexVBOID;

void render() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(x, 1.0f, z, x + lx, 1.0f, z+lz, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glPushMatrix();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexVBOID);

    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);


    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(3*sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(5*sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(8*sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glPopMatrix();      

    glutSwapBuffers();

    //std::cout << glGetError();
}

void resize(int w, int h) {
    if(h == 0)
        h = 1;

    float ratio = 1.0*w/h;
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    gluPerspective(45, ratio, 1, 1000);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void processKeys(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {

}

void specialKeys(int key, int x, int y) {
        float fraction = 0.1f;

    switch(key) {
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        angle -= 0.01f;
        lx = sin(angle);
        lz = -cos(angle);
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        angle += 0.01f;
        lx = sin(angle);
        lz = -cos(angle);
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        x += lx * fraction;
        z += lz * fraction;
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        x -= lx * fraction;
        z -= lz * fraction;
        break;
    }
}

void initVBO() {
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex)*24, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(Vertex)*24, &cube[0]);

    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(3*sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(5*sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(8*sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    glGenBuffers(1, &indexVBOID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexVBOID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 36*sizeof(GLubyte), &cubeIndex[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("FC");

    //glew initialization
    glewInit();
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);


    initializeCube();
    initVBO();

    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutIdleFunc(render);

    glutKeyboardFunc(processKeys);
    glutSpecialFunc(specialKeys);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


    glutMainLoop();

    return 1;
}
```

Terrain.cpp just initializes the data for the cube:

```
//terrain.h
#ifndef _TERRAIN_
#define _TERRAIN_

#include "include.h"

#define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) ((char *)NULL + (i))

// Location/Normals
#define X_POS 0
#define Y_POS 1
#define Z_POS 2
// Texture Coordinates
#define U_POS 0
#define V_POS 1
// colors
#define R_POS 0
#define G_POS 1
#define B_POS 2
#define A_POS 3

const GLfloat cubeSize = 1.0f;

typedef struct Vertex {
    GLfloat location[3];
    GLfloat tex[2];
    GLfloat normal[3];
    GLfloat color[4];
    GLubyte padding[16];
} Vertex;

static Vertex cube[24];
static GLubyte cubeIndex[36];

void pushVertex(Vertex* toPush, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z);

void pushNormal(Vertex* toPush, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z);

void pushTexCoord(Vertex* toPush, GLfloat u, GLfloat v);

void pushTriangleIndices(GLubyte index[], int triangleNum, GLubyte a, GLubyte b, GLubyte c);

void initializeCube();

#endif
```

And finally:

```
#ifndef __INCLUDE__
#define __INCLUDE__

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#endif
```

If anyone wants to see terrain.cpp, I will post it.

As far as I can tell, nothing is rendering at all. If I attempt to render in immediate mode, it works just fine. And, if it's any help, I tried copying the tutorial's code verbatim (adding in a couple of lines for Glew since the author originally wrote it without Glew) and the result was a white screen, even after clearing the screen to black.

Comment: Any particular reason you're enabling texcoord pointer and disabling gl_texture_2d? What is your render supposed to look like, if not a white screen? Also check for errors with glGetError if you're not currently.

Comment: I disabled gl_texture_2d as a lead I found on a post about a similar problem. I must have forgotten to remove that line. I'm trying for a white cube on a black background, which I'll later add a texture to. I've also been checking for errors with glGetError, but I haven't found any so far.

Comment: As a side note, those `gl...Pointer` calls in `initVBO` are obsolete, as well as your `glBufferSubData` call, just use `glBufferData` since you're updating the whole buffer anyway.

Comment: What vertex coordinates does your cube have?

Comment: Alright, I've removed the call to glBufferSubData as recommended. In regards to the vertex coordinates, I have a constant representing the length of a side, so, for example, the bottom back left vertex is at (-width/2, -width/2, -width/2). I don't think that's where the problem is, though because I just modified the code to render a simple triangle, but got the same result. If anyone thinks seeing "terrain.h" -- where the vertex data is setup -- I'd be happy to post it.

Answer (score 2):

Having nothing render at all is a common problem. Unfortunately, I don't know exactly what's wrong with your program, but here's a debugging strategy I often find helpful. Try rendering a single triangle in immediate mode, as opposed to using VBOs. In case you're not familiar with the term, immediate mode means things like `glVertex3f`.

If you can make the triangle appear in immediate mode, then your problem is most likely with the VBO. If you can't, then you can zero in on potential problems in your matrices or in the way you've configured the OpenGL context.

By the way, I'd recommend switching from the fixed function pipeline (`glVertexPointer`, etc) to GLSL shaders. It seems intimidating at first, but it's extremely flexible. And once you get into it, you'll find that it's actually more intuitive than the extremely finicky and opaque fixed function pipeline.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post, rendering in immediate mode worked fine. I ended up just ditching GLUT and dealt with windowing myself. Now it's working just fine, but I suppose what went wrong with the GLUT version will remain a mystery. Thank you.